# cannot get tempfilepath with multer

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, multer

With fileupload we can get tempfilepath but with multer any way to get tempfile path?I want to upload files to cloudinary using temp file path.. Here is my code.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: (req, file, cb)=>{
    cb(null, 'uploads')
},
filename: (req, file, cb)=>{
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
},
useTempFiles: true
})

const upload = multer({storage});

app.post("/upload", upload.single('photo'), (req, res, next)=>{
let fileinfo = req.file;
console.log(fileinfo);
cloudinary.uploader.upload(fileinfo.tempFilePath,{width: 70, height: 90,           crop: "fit"}, (err,result)=>{
        console.error(err);
        console.log(result.url);
});
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
filename: (req, file, cb)=>{
 cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
}
})

const upload = multer({storage});

app.post("/upload", upload.single('photo'), (req, res, 
next)=>{
let fileinfo = req.file;
console.log(fileinfo);
cloudinary.uploader.upload(fileinfo.path,{width: 70, 
height: 90,crop: "fit"}, (err,result)=>{
    console.error(err);
    console.log(result.url);
});
})
```

Make this changes to your code and try this

Answer (score 0):

Multer gives you access to the uploaded files before storing them.

If you want, however, to store files and access them like you do in PHP, you should use the DiskStorage option of the Multer.

> ```
> var storage = multer.diskStorage({
>   destination: function (req, file, cb) {
>     cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
>   },
>   filename: function (req, file, cb) {
>     cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
>   }
> })
> ```

Both the arguments taken by the `diskStorage` are functions. One function determines the upload folder and the other one the file name.